# How to calculate Memory taken by a Image to load into memory Android?

Tags: android, image, memory-management

I have one straight forward question how much memory take an Image to load into memory. How to calculate this. And which parameter matter while doing it?

Comment: Why its comes under not a real question? please comment if you have any issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's about width * height * bits_per_pixels/8 in bytes. I don't know why you need this though. If, when creating an image you get OutOfMemoryError you can catch it and scale an image then

Comment: +1 for response but We can not catch OutOfMemoryError. You should know that

Comment: In Java/Android we can catch it like this try { Bitmap.createBitmap(..) .. } catch(OutOfMemeoryError x) {.. scale here ..}